# How would one let a user point their custom domain to a specific route in a client-side react app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, dns

I have a simple react app with a firebase backend. My app lets people create profile pages. I want to let people point their domain to their profile page. I don't even know where to start or what to search for. How would one let users point their custom domain to a specific route in a client-side react app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's **a lot** involved here, so I'm just going explain a very first basic step here.

One of the first things is that you'll need to be able to point multiple domains to the same back-end code, and then service different content based on the incoming domain. So that www.joshpittman.mytld will serve different content than www.frankvanpuffelen.mytld. This typically requires that you can programmatically map new domains to the existing backend code, which then serves different content based on the requested domain.

Firebase Hosting *does* allow you to mapping multiple domains to a single project, but there is no API to add new domains. You'd have to manually add each user's domain in the Firebase console, which seems unfeasible at any reasonable scale.

So if you want to implement this functionality, you might want to consider other options for hosting, specifically ones that have an API to add domain mappings, or that allow wildcard mappings. Since recommending specific ones is off topic on Stack Overflow, I recommend you do some searches with those specific terms to find good options.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Super helpful as always.